# Kotlin Android studio : SQlite auto increment isn't working

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a issue where when I enter the first record into my data it goes into slot ID = 1. But if i enter another record it doesnt increment to id = 2 and tries to use ID = 1 even though i  stated AUTOINCREMENT in the SQL code.

SQLite class

```
class SQLiteHelper(context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION){
    companion object{
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "anki.db"
        private const val TBL_WORD = "tbl_word"
        private const val ID = "id"
        private const val DATE = "date"
        private const val ENGLISHWORD = "englishWord"
        private const val JAPANESEWORD = "jpnWord"
        private const val TIME = "time" 
        private const val ANSWER = "answer"
    }

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val createTblWord = ("CREATE TABLE "+ TBL_WORD + "("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ DATE + " TEXT,"+ ENGLISHWORD + " TEXT,"
            + JAPANESEWORD + " TEXT,"+ TIME + " INTEGER,"+ ANSWER + " INTEGER"+")")
    db?.execSQL(createTblWord)
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TBL_WORD")
    onCreate(db)
}

fun insertWord(word: WordModel): Long{
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val contentValues = ContentValues()
    contentValues.put(ID,word.id)
    contentValues.put(DATE,word.date)
    contentValues.put(ENGLISHWORD,word.engword)
    contentValues.put(JAPANESEWORD,word.jpword)
    contentValues.put(TIME,word.time)
    contentValues.put(ANSWER,word.answer)

    val success = db.insert(TBL_WORD, null , contentValues)
    db.close()
    return success
}
```

Main class add word method

```
    private fun addWord(){
    val date = etDate.text.toString()
    val jpword = etJpWord.text.toString()
    val engword = etEngWord.text.toString()

    if(date.isEmpty() || jpword.isEmpty() || engword.isEmpty()){//必要な情報が入力してない場合
        Toast.makeText(this,"必要な情報を入力してください。",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        clearEditText()
    }else{
        val word = WordModel(date=date, jpword = jpword, engword = engword)
        val status = sqliteHelper.insertWord(word)
        //Check Insert success or not success
        if(status > -2){
            Toast.makeText(this,"単語を追加しました",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"データが保存されてないようです。",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldnt ID auto increment ?? Tried debug and Id clearly doesnt auto increment and tries to use the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share your WordModel? What do you use for `id` when create a new word in your `addWord()` method:

```
val word = WordModel(date=date, jpword = jpword, engword = engword)
```

Perhaps you use default `id` value of your `WordModel` like here: `data class WordModel(id: Long? = 1, ...)`. And if it's true you can change the default value of id here to be like `data class WordModel(id: Long? = null, ...)` and it should work to insert auto-generated `id` values for db rows.

In another case you can use base SQLite `BaseColumns._ID` for creating your table like

```
"CREATE TABLE $TBL_WORD (${BaseColumns._ID} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $ENGLISHWORD TEXT, $JAPANESEWORD TEXT, etc)"
```

and then just don't put `id` like a value at all in your `SQLiteHelper::insertWord(word: WordModel)` method. It will be automatically generated like an auto incremented value for any new row in db.

You can see example in [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply,

Word model class is here,



@Parcelize data class WordModel(
    var id: Int = 1,
    var date: String = "",
    var engword: String = "",
    var jpword: String = "",
    var time: Int = 0,
    var answer: Int = 0
) : Parcelable

}

Comment: Okay, I see you use default value for your id like 1 so that's the issue :) you can set it to null for example or use another approach what I described above.

Comment: I posted another question , if you have time could you help me out? would appreiciate it alot because ive been stuck for awhile

Answer (score 0):

//try to change key_id query like this

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
            String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("  
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"  
                    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";  
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);  
        }
```